# Bundle.js not recognizing one of my files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please bear with me because I am a javascript newbie, and just starting to learn react.

I am trying to make a small app but I keep getting an error that one of my files is not found... specifically this:

bundle.js:56 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components/search_bar"

My file structure is that I have my index.js in a folder called src, then my search bar(search_bar.js) in a folder called components. I have triple checked the spelling on them but I continue to get this error.

This is my index.js

```
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//Create a componant (some /HTML)

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyC3Z3qTpvAacDLYEIxaueKflFJbWvdIHsw';

  const App = () => {
    return (
     <div>
      <SearchBar />
     </div>
   );
  }

// Put that componant on the page (the DOM)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

And this is my search_bar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  contructor(props) {

    super(props);
    // when user updates the search bar this term will get updated.
    this.state = { term: ''};

  }

  render() {
    //update state
    //use set state everywhere besides constructor!!
    return (
      <div>
      <input onChange={event => this.setState({term: event.target.value})} 
/>
      Value of the input: {this.state.term}
      </div>
    );
  }

}


export default SearchBar;
```

Any Ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: AHHH I left an 's' out of constructor... so search_bar.js was unable to compile.  I have been looking at this for about an hour now...

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the following directory structure?

`my_project/src/index.js`

`my_project/src/components/search_bar.js`

It seems like your current directory structure might instead look like this:
`my_project/src/index.js`, `my_project/components/search_bar.js`

Comment: index.js is in src and search_bar is in components.

Answer (score 0):

AHHH I left an 's' out of constructor... so search_bar.js was unable to compile. I have been looking at this for about an hour now...

Comment: where exactly did you forget an "s"?

Comment: I wrote 

contructor(props) 

when it really should have been constructor(props)